# Import error python

Tags: python

In Python, when I use this import statement breze.learn.mlp import iter_minibatches, am getting the following errors.

Here `iter_minibatches` is a function defined in mlp.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vinod/PycharmProjects/MLPonTheano/MLPbreze.py", line 15, in <module>
    from breze.learn.mlp import Mlp, FastDropoutNetwork
  File "/home/vinod/breze/breze/learn/mlp.py", line 22, in <module>
    from breze.learn.base import SupervisedModel
  File "/home/vinod/breze/breze/learn/base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from breze.learn.mlp import iter_minibatches
ImportError: cannot import name iter_minibatches
```

Comment: *"Here `iter_minibatches` is a function defined in mlp.py"* -- can you prove it?

Comment: What does `dir(breze.learn.mlp)` output?

Comment: def iter_minibatches(lst, batch_size, dims, n_cycles=False, random_state=None):

    print 'inside iter mini batches:', lst[0]
    batches = [minibatches(i, batch_size, d) for i, d in zip(lst, dims)]
....

Comment: breze.learn.mlp is a seperate file where it contains classes and seperate functions

Comment: @Sam: note the circular import.

Comment: @Sam : so how to solve it ?

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular import; `mlp` imports `base` imports `mlp`:

```
# executing mlp.py
  File "/home/vinod/breze/breze/learn/mlp.py", line 22, in <module>
    from breze.learn.base import SupervisedModel
# executing base.py
  File "/home/vinod/breze/breze/learn/base.py", line 21, in <module>
# this tries to import from mlp again, but mlp isn't done yet
    from breze.learn.mlp import iter_minibatches
```

Any line after the `from breze.learn.base import SupervisedModel` will not yet have been executed so importing any object defined by those lines will fail.

Avoid circular imports, or if you must have them, delay importing in one of the modules to make sure the objects you need in the other are defined.

Comment: Good catch @MartijnPieters!

Comment: I am using **from breze.learn.mlp import iter_minibatches** in base.py and  this import  **from breze.learn.base import SupervisedModel** is used in mlp.py...


Can you suggest me how to solve it.... I am newbie to python

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am facing this problem only after adding  from breze.learn.mlp import iter_minibatches in base.py

Comment: @Vinodprime: yes, and that caused the circular import. Do you *have* to have that import there? Can you reorganise your objects to not have `mlp` import something from `base` again?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have to use iter_minibatches in base.py, so I don't know wat to do

Comment: @Vinodprime: you'll have to update your question with your actual code and uses for me to be able to say anything sensible here. You need to avoid importing `mlp` or `base` until after all the objects the other module needs have been defined, but I cannot tell you how to change your code without seeing it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the help, Now I have understood the circular dependency and I have paused the function such that only it's been used in the respective place